# Group action of Free Product Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-actions, free-product

Suppose I have two groups G and H, and K is their free product, K = $G*H$ Suppose G acts on a set X with action $\phi$ and H acts on X by action $\psi$, then what is the action of K on X.

I think the action of $K$ on X should be for any word $g_1h_1, \dots h_ng_n$ repeatedly apply the action of $g_i$ or $h_i$ for every word in the group $K$. I think this is a group action because it preserves the relations that generate the group K since it must preserve all relation for the group G and H. I am not sure is this line of reasoning is correct.
From the universal property of the free product, I know a group action exists, I do not know if this is the correct action that is induced.

The reason I am unsure is the generalization of this problem. If G and H act on different sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ that are not disjoint, I should be able to define the same group action as before of K action on $X_1 \cup X_2$, but this feels strange, and I do not know if it is correct.

To sum up:

1. Is the group action of K on X defined correctly?
2. How does K act on $X_1 \cup X_2$ given G acts on $X_1$ and H on $X_2$?

Comment: The action of each of $G$ and $H$ induce homomorphisms to $S(X)$, the permutation group on $X$. Apply the universal property of the free product to get a morphism from $K$, which defines an action. For the second, let $G$ and $H$ act on the union.

Comment: What does the morphism 'look like' when I use the universal property of the free product? I think it should be exactly what I described

Comment: @ArturoMagidin https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/36082/1650

Comment: You can extend the action of $G$ on $X_1$ to an action on $X_1 \cup X_2$ by letting all elements of $G$ fix all elements of $X_2 \setminus X_1$. Similarly for $H$.

Comment: I was wondering if this generalize to the amalgamated free product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is the action that is defined for $G \ast H$.

**Claim:** A group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ can be alternatively defined as a group homomorphism

$$ G \rightarrow S(X)$$

where $S(X)$ is the group of permutations (self-bijections) of $X$.

**Proof:**
A group element is mapped to the permutation "act with g": $$g.(-) : X\rightarrow X, x \mapsto g.x$$
the axiom for a group action
$$g.h.x = (gh).x$$
is now precisely stating that the map $g \mapsto g.(-)$ is a group homomorphism to the group of permutations. $\square$

**Recall:** The universal property of a free product of groups is the following:

A free product of two groups $G$ and $H$ is a group $G \ast H $, such that group homomorphisms out of it

$$ G \ast H \rightarrow  G'$$

are precisely pairs of group homomorphisms out of $G$ and $H$ :
$$ \varphi: G \rightarrow G' \qquad \psi: H \rightarrow G' $$

If you go through the construction of a free product of groups, which is words in $G$ and $H$ modulo the equivalence relation as specified by the individual group operations, you will find that the induced map out of the free product is given by:
$$ [ g_1h_1 \dots g_n h_n ] \mapsto \varphi(g_1) \psi(h_1) \dots \varphi(g_n) \psi(h_n) $$
Which is to say "simply apply the group homomorphism to every letter of the word *in $G'$*. Moreover one has to check - I suspect this is the source of your doubts, so I suggest you do this - that this assignment is independent of the choice of representative and defines a group homomorphism.
In the current situation $G'= S(X)$.

2. Canonically there is no such action, since the maps
   $$G \rightarrow S(X_1) \qquad H \rightarrow S(X_2)$$
   target different permutation groups. But there is a way to fix this:
   we can identify permutations $S(X_1) \hookrightarrow
   S(X)$ by those permutations which fix elements of $X_2 \setminus X_1$. Analogously for $S(X_2)$. These two group homomorphisms give rise to an action of $G\ast H$ on $X$ which is given as in the previous example, with the special ingredient, that elements of $G$, $H$ act trivially on $X_2\setminus X_1$,$X_1\setminus X_2$ respectively, that is to say that:

$$g.x_2 = x_2 \quad \forall x_2 \in X_2\setminus X_1 $$
and
$$h.x_1 = x_1 \quad \forall x_1 \in X_1 \setminus X_2 $$

Comment: Thanks, this a great answer, but I am not sure why $G$ acts trivially on $X_1$, shouldn't it act trivially on elements $X_2$? In particular, doesn't this mean that the entire action of G*H is trivial?

Comment: I am glad that I could be of help. :-) You are absolutely correct, I got mixed up with the indices. That was my mistake, I corrected the answer.

Comment: No, it does not mean, that the entire action of $G \ast H$ is trivial. $G$ still could act nontrivially on  $X_1$ and $H$ on $X_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! What about elements in $X_1 \cap X_2$. Your answer seems to imply they are acted on trivially. As a follow up: couldn't I have defined the action of G to on X to only fix the elements in $X_1 \setminus X_2$? Then the action of G*H would not be trivial on these elements?

Comment: Thank you for your followup question! I made a mistake and assumed $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be disjoint, I now fixed my answer. 
Why is it not possible to extend the action of $G$ to be trivial for every element of $X_2$ ? For elements of the interaction we already have a definition of $g.x$.

Comment: I was wondering if this generalize to the amalgamated free product?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Also please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Concretely, if G and H are not disjoint, and I take the amalgamated free product, then will the action of that amalgamated free product be the same as the one you described?

Comment: The most important condition to keep in mind is that the action of $G$ and $H$ on their intersection agrees. Then indeed one gets by the universal property of the pushout a unique homomorphism to $S(X)$, which is given by the same formula, as I have described. Key difference: the equivalence relation on the amalgamated free product imposes further relations so that  group elements are equivalence classes of words, not words. On wikipedia, there is a comprehensive construction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product